Each of A, B, and C draw a card without replacement from a 52-card deck. What is the probability that A's face value is higher than the rest?

Case 1: All three cards have equal face values. There are 13 such cases since there are 13 different ranks.
Case 2: Two cards have equal face value and the third card has a lower value. Initially, I calculated the number of such cases as 3×(12+11+…+1)=234.
Case 3: Two cards have equal face value and the third card has a higher value.
Case 4: All three cards have different face values.

The first 2 cases are to be excluded. And total number of outcomes = 13^3
Probability that A wins is [13^3-(234+13)]/3 / 13^3 = 50/169
However, this is not the right answer. Can I ask what is wrong with my counting appr?

Case 1 should be 52. For each of the 13 ranks, you can select 3 out 4 cards matching that rank. So there are 4 possibilities for each of those 13. This totals 52.

Your $13^3$ is wrong.  The denominator of the answer should divide $52 \times 51 \times 50=132600$.  But $13^2=169$ does not. If you were drawing with replacement then it would have to divide $52 \times 52 \times 52$ and does.

@Henry does this mean that my other cases are also counted wrongly since I have to factor the drawing without replacement into my counting? Only focusing on the face value of cards won't reflect the actual number of outcomes

@clement Your cases are all "with" replacement.

You can use symmetry to simplify calculations.
There are $52 \cdot 48 \cdot 44$ ways to select cards of $3$ different ranks.  Of these, exactly $\frac 13$ of them will have $A$ choosing the card of highest rank.  This accounts for $\frac 13(52 \cdot 48 \cdot 44)=36608$ cases.
There are $52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 + 52 \cdot 48 \cdot 6$ ways to choose three cards such that exactly one of them is paired.  (The first card either will or won't be paired in the first draw.)  Of these, exactly half will pair the lower card, and $A$ will have the unpaired card exactly $\frac 13$ of the times when the lower card is paired.  This accounts for $\frac 16(52 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 + 52 \cdot 48 \cdot 6)=3744$ cases.
Thus, there are $36608+3744=40352$ ways to draw cards without replacement such that $A$ has undisputed possession of the highest rank.  There are $52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50=132600$ ways to draw three cards without replacement (where order matters).  The probability that $A$ wins outright is therefore $\dfrac{40352}{132600} = \dfrac{388}{1275} \approx 0.3043$.

Another calculation would be that A has the highest value and that B and C are strictly smaller.

Without replacement, if A's value is $a$, this can be done $4 \times (4a-4) \times (4a-5)$ ways, out of $52 \times 51 \times 50$ total ways, so with probability $$\sum\limits_{a=1}^{13}\dfrac{ 4 \times (4a-4) \times (4a-5) }{ 52 \times 51 \times 50} = \dfrac{388}{1275} \approx 0.304$$
With replacement, if A's value is $a$, this can be done $4 \times (4a-4) \times (4a-4)$ ways, out of $52 \times 52 \times 52$ total ways, so with probability $$\sum\limits_{a=1}^{13}\dfrac{ 4 \times (4a-4) \times (4a-4) }{ 52 \times 52 \times 52} = \dfrac{50}{169} \approx 0.296$$

Your original calculation was the with replacement case.

I would add intuitive ideas here.  First of all, if you were guaranteed that A,B,C drew cards of different ranks, then you would have, by reasons of symmetry, that the probability that A is the high card is $1/3 = 0.333...$  So, in general, you should expect a probability slightly lower than that.  Further, if the drawing is without replacement, then it is slightly more difficult to have 2 or more of the 3 cards being the same rank.  This explains why the probability with replacement is lower than the probability without replacement. ...see next comment

The (somewhat) fatal (but perhaps neglible) flaw in the previous comment is that you can have (for example) A drawing a trey, and B,C each drawing a deuce.  So, just because the 3 cards drawn are not of 3 different ranks does not imply that A was not the high card.

Your approach is feasible, however there is an easier way to solve the problem.  First, I will show how I would implement your approach, and then I will show the easier way.
As the title of your posted question asserts, I will assume that the cards are drawn without replacement.

$~\underline{\text{Implementing Your Approach}}$
When computing the probability that certain cards are drawn by A,B, and C, the computation should (in general) have format
$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = 52 \times 51 \times 50.$$
That is, there are $~52~$ choices for the card drawn by A.  Once A draws a card, there are then $~51~$ choices for the card drawn by B, and so forth.
I will assign the variables $~N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4,~$ to represent the number of ways that each of Case 1, Case 2, Case 3, and Case 4 could have occurred, respectively.
Case 1: 
All three cards have equal face values.
There are $~13~$ ranks that could be the rank of all three cards. 
So, reserve the factor of $~13,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that all three cards were an Ace.
This assumption is based on the idea of symmetry.  That is, the subsequent  calculation here will be the exact same if all three cards were a deuce, or all three cards were a trey, and so forth.
Similar to the $~D = (52 \times 51 \times 50)~$ computation, there are $~(4 \times 3 \times 2)~$ ways that A,B,C could have each drawn an Ace.
Therefore,
$$N_1 = \frac{13 \times (4 \times 3 \times 2)}{52 \times 51 \times 50}.$$
Case 2: 
Two cards have equal face value and the third card has a lower value.
This is complicated.
First, there are three possibilities for whether the low card is drawn by A, B or C.  So, I will reserve the factor of $~3,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that the low card was drawn by C.
Assuming that Ace is high, assign the ranks of 11,12,13,14 to Jacks, Queens, Kings, Aces, respectively.  So, the rank of a card is some element $~k \in \{2,3,\cdots, 14\}.~$
Further:

The number of ways that A and B could each have drawn a card from rank  $~k~$ is $~(4 \times 3).~$

Assuming that A and B each drew a card from rank $~k,~$ there are now,  $~4 \times (k-2)~$ cards below rank $~k,~$ that C could have drawn.


Therefore,
$$N_2 = 3 \times (4 \times 3) \times \left\{ ~\sum_{k=2}^{14} \left[ ~4 \times (k-2) ~\right] ~\right\}.$$
Case 3: 
Two cards have equal face value and the third card has a higher value.
Here, you have two choices.  One choice is to engage in analysis virtually identical to the analysis in Case 2, above.  The second (easier) choice is to rely on the symmetry argument, that assuming (for example) that A and B drew cards of the same rank, it is equally likely that C drew a card above A,B as it is that C drew a card below A,B.
This leads to the conclusion that
$$N_3 = N_2 = 3 \times (4 \times 3) \times \left\{ ~\sum_{k=2}^{14} \left[ ~4 \times (k-2) ~\right] ~\right\}.$$
Case 4:
All three cards have different face values.
Case 1, Case 2, Case 3, Case 4 are mutually exclusive, and since they cover all possibilities of how A,B,C could have drawn cards, you have that
$$N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4 = D.$$
Therefore, you have that
$$N_4 = D - (N_1 + N_2 + N_3).$$
Therefore, you have that the probability that Case 4 occurred is in fact
$$\frac{N_4}{D} = \frac{D - (N_1 + N_2 + N_3)}{D}$$
where the computations for $~D, N_1, N_2, N_3~$ have already been given.

Edit
An elegant, but somewhat complicated alternative computation for $~N_4~$ is as follows:
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{13}{3} = \frac{13 \times 12 \times 11}{3 \times 2 \times 1}~$ ways that the three ranks may be selected, so that each of A,B,C selected a card from one of these ranks.
So, at this point, you have a reduced deck of $~12~$ cards.
So, there are $~12~$ choices for which card that A chose.
Then, because B must not choose a card of the same rank as A, there are $~8~$ choices for which card that B chose. 
Then, similarly, there are now $~4~$ choices for which card that C chose.
Therefore,
$$N_4 = \binom{13}{3} \times (12 \times 8 \times 4).$$

Unfortunately, your implementation is incomplete, and contains two further mistakes.

Mistake 1:
Apparently, you assumed that the only way that A could be the high card is if Case 4 occurred.  This is wrong, because A could also be the high card if Case 3 occurred, and B,C drew cards of the same rank, while A drew a card of a higher rank.
For example, you could have A drawing a trey, while each of B,C drew a deuce.

Mistake 2:
Overlooking Mistake 1, your approach did specifically attempt to compute the probability that Case 4 occurred.
However, just because Case 4 occurred, and all three of A,B,C drew cards of different ranks, does not necessarily imply that A was the one who drew the high card. 
In fact, the shortcut resolution to Mistake 2, is that by reasons of symmetry, you have to apply the scaling factor of $~(1/3).~$ This is because if A,B,C drew cards of different ranks, there is a $~(1/3)~$ probability that A was the high card.



$~\underline{\text{Implementing An Easier Way}}$
The computation for
$$D = (52 \times 51 \times 50)$$ will again be used here.
Further the variable $~k \in \{2,3,\cdots,14\},~$ will again be used to represent the rank of the cards.
To compute $~N,~$ so that the probability may be expressed as $~\dfrac{N}{D},~$ I will specifically create the helper function $~f(k) ~: ~k \in \{2,3,\cdots,14\},~$ so that $~f(k)~$ represents the number of ways that A is the high card, assuming that A drew a card of rank $~k.$
Then, you will have that
$$N = \sum_{k=2}^{14} f(k).$$
Suppose that A draws a card of rank $~k.~$ If $~k = 2,~$ then clearly $~f(k) = 0.$  What happens if $~k > 2~?$
First of all, there are $~4~$ different ways that A could have drawn a card of rank $~k.~$
Then there are $~4 \times (k - 2)~$ cards below the rank of $~k,~$ that each of B,C must draw.  Therefore, there are $~4 \times (k-2)~$ cards that B must draw, and then $~[ ~4 \times (k - 2) ~] - 1 ~$ cards that C must draw.
Therefore, when $~k > 2,~$ you have that
$$f(k) = 4 \times [ ~4 \times (k - 2) ~] \times \left\{ ~[ ~4 \times (k - 2) ~] - 1 ~\right\}$$
$$= 4 \times (4k - 8) \times (4k - 9).$$
Therefore, since the case of $~f(2) = 0~$ may be discarded, the overall probability that A was the high card is
$$\frac{\sum_{k=3}^{14} f(k)}{D} = \frac{\sum_{k=3}^{14} [ ~4 \times (4k - 8) \times (4k - 9) ~]}{52 \times 51 \times 50}.$$

thank you for the detailed answer!

By symmetry, the probability $p$ that A's card is higher than the other two is $1/3$ of the probability that there is a unique highest card, that is:
$$p=\frac13\sum_{k=1}^{12}\frac{4\binom{4k}2}{\binom{52}3}=\frac4{3\binom{52}3}\sum_{k=1}^{12}\binom{4k}2$$
where $\frac{4\binom{4k}2}{\binom{52}3}$ is the probability of drawing one card of rank $k$ and two cards of lower rank, the ranks being numbered from $0$ to $12$.
Now
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{4k}2=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{4k(4k-1)}2=8\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-2\sum_{k=1}^nk=$$$$=8\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6-2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{n(n+1)(8n+1)}3,$$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{12}\binom{4k}2=\frac{12\cdot13\cdot97}3=52\cdot97,$$
and
$$p=\frac4{3\binom{52}3}\cdot52\cdot97=\frac8{52\cdot51\cdot50}\cdot52\cdot97=\frac{8\cdot97}{51\cdot50}=\boxed{\frac{388}{1275}}.$$
